# Views do not update inside the ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using a `ForEach` to parse a list of models and create a view for each of them, Each view contains a `Button` and a `Text`, the `Button` toggles a visibility state which should hide the text and change the Button's title (Invisible/Visible).

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var colors: [MyColor] = [MyColor(val: "Blue"), MyColor(val: "Yellow"), MyColor(val: "Red")]

    var body: some View {

        ForEach(colors, id: \.uuid) { color in
            ButtonColorView(color: color.val)
        }

    }
}

struct ButtonColorView: View {

    var color: String

    @State var visible = true

    var body: some View {

        if visible {
            return AnyView(  HStack {
                Button("Invisible") {
                    self.visible.toggle()
                }
                Text(color)
            })
        } else {
            return AnyView(
                Button("Visible") {
                    self.visible.toggle()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}



class MyColor: Identifiable {
    let uuid = UUID()
    let val: String

    init(val: String) {
        self.val = val
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working, the views inside the `ForEach` do not change when the `Button` is pressed. I replaced the `Foreach` with `ButtonColorView(color: colors[0].val)` and it seems to work, so I'd say the problem is at `ForEach`.

I also tried breakpoints in `ButtonColorView` and it seems the view is called when the Button is triggered returning the right view, anyways the view does not update on screen.

So, am I using the `ForEach` in a wrong way ?

[image]

This problem occurs in a more complex app, but I tried to extract it in this small example. To summarize it: I need `ButtonColorView` to return different Views depending of its state (visibility in this case)

PS: I'm using Xcode 11 Beta 6

Comment: Could you please share the initializer of ButtonColorView with the color property?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. There is no initializer for ButtonColorView because it's a struct and I use the default init: `ButtonColorView(color: color.val)`. This is the whole code so you can copy it in Xcode if you wanna test it

Comment: You created a struct object of type ContentView, that inherits the View. View Struct is not in Foundation framework so we don't have the View Struct so we can't test it. The initializer View(color: MyColor) is in your View Struct file whitch you haven't posted.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. View is in SwiftUI framework, as I mentioned in the title this is a SwiftUI app ...

Comment: Try updating the color on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ForEach correctly. I think it's the if statement within ButtonColorView's body that's causing problems. Try this:

```
struct ButtonColorView: View {

    var color: String

    @State var visible = true

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(visible ? "Invisible" : "Visible") {
                self.visible.toggle()
            }
            if visible {
                Text(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also try something like this:

```
struct ButtonColorView: View {

    var color: String

    @State var visible = true

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if visible {
                HStack {
                    Button("Invisible") {
                        self.visible.toggle()
                    }
                    Text(color)
                }
            } else {
                Button("Visible") {
                    self.visible.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As I said this is a small example to ilustrate a problem that accurs in a complex app. Your solution solves the problem in this particular case, unfortunately I can't apply it in my app, the problem is that I need `ButtonColorView` to return a different View depending of its state, it may be a `Text`, `Section` or `EmptyView`. In your solution `ButtonColorView` always returns a `HStack` which makes it working, but in the real case I can't wrap everything in a `HStack`. Thank you!

Comment: The problem definitely is with the if statement within ButtonColorView's body. Maybe you can share more of your actual project - it would make it easier to help.

Comment: The actual `ButtonColorView`looks like this `var body: some View {
        
        let props = model.properties

        let view = "Whatever view"
        
        if props.visible {
            return AnyView(view)
        } else {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }` so I can't remove the `if` and I can't add the HStack either bacause it breaks by design :(

Comment: If I use `List` instead of `ForEach` it seems to work just fine, but I do not need a list